# How do we add an extra field with using values from a separate list using django orm in table?

Tags: django, django-orm

Below is the sample list from which I want to get names of person using their id's.
Sample_list =

```
[{'name': 'Name 1', 'id': 1154}, {'name': 'Name 3', 'id': 1156}, {'name': 'Name 3', 'id': 663}]
```

How do we create an extra field in another existing table which has the only **id** of the user in it?

In the end, using this, I want to extract the id, name and few other details.

I am using `Django=1.9.1` for this.

```
# User model -
class User(ModelBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)`

# Details model -
class Details(ModelBase):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_id')
```

Now `created_by` in `class Details` is ID. I want the id and username for `Details model` from User.

Comment: Is this a list? Or a queryset? Please provide a MWE.

Comment: `[{'name': 'Name 1', 'id': 1154}, {'name': 'Name 3', 'id': 1156}, {'name': 'Name 3', 'id': 663}]` this is a list I have created from a separate table.

Comment: But why did you constructed a list? Now it loses the flexibility to create a join?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah I know I was wrong here. But without creating list how do I create an extra field in the other table?

Comment: is the table has foreign key to User model?

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes.

Comment: @MohammadAli Added

Answer (score 0):

when you extract data from db with user id. you can access to username also.

```
myDetails = Details.objects.get(created_by__id = 2)
print(myDetails.created_by.username)
```

and for defining a model, you can use models.Model not ModelBase

```
from django.db import models

class Details(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: if you want to write an API, in django rest you can do this with serializers